# file_get_contents() returns cached page

Tags: php, linux, curl, dns, browser-cache

Really bizarre issue I seem to have.

I'm calling a file_get_contents() on a url to get the html for an email.

Like this -

```
file_get_contents('http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/email.php?name=Seb');
```

I've used this method 1000s of times.

When I call the url I get a 404 header even though the file exists. Upon further investigation, when I call the root domain I get some default holding page -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=defaultsite" />
<!-- UK -->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I've checked the DNS records and they seem correct. When I ping the url I get the correct server IP. If I run from the command line -

```
curl http://www.mywebsite.co.uk
```

I get the same default page. Yet if I curl it on my machine I get the correct homepage. Is there some kind of cache?!

Tried numerous searches but coming up stuck. Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Curl and file_get_contents both do not cache results. If you connection goes through a proxy, it is possible that the proxy is responding with a cached version of the page, but unlikely. There really isn't much information to go on. It is possible that the page was requested enough that they are blocking it and serving a different page. Also possible that they block certain user agents or similar requests.

Comment: If they choose to block certain request and replay with a 404 response, they are to blame!

Comment: It's my server/website so not blocking anything. It's more like a server dns cache rather than a page cache.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a cache you could avoid it by adding a param to your request with the current timestamp in it.

```
file_get_contents('http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/email.php?name=Seb&t='.time());
```

It will force the server to fetch the requested resource.

Comment: It seems to be more like a dns cache rather than file cache as it returns 404 for a page that exists. I also tried the get parameters in case too.

Answer (score 1):

So I've managed to figure out the problem.

It seems this particular domain has both an A record and an AAAA (IPv6) record. Which point to different servers. It seems most machines are using the A record, while for some reason this server is using the AAAA record.

Not that easy to spot initially as the common DNS checkers only show A records that I've seen.

I found this out by calling -

```
curl -v -I http://www.example.com
```

This returns the IP address of the call.

I hope this helps someone else, I've lost a few hours to this!